# JSON data post to the URL opened in CefSharp browser with example

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am opening a webpage in the cefsharp browser and trying to send a set of JSON data to my website's .aspx page along with query string. While the query string is not an issue but sending the JSON data to the same URL is what I am trying to fix. Earlier I was using Window's native WebBrowser control's Navigate method where I was passing the URL along with query string as well as a byte array. But, I don't find any such method to post the data. Various discussion and posts regarding the same don't have a clear example. Can you provide a sample code/example to show how to achieve that? Here is the code I've been using:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.Address = "https://webhook.site";
browser.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
browser.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
browser.RequestHandler = this;
browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        browser.LoadUrlWithPostData("https://webhook.site/#/cba9d04b-01ff-40ef-b223-0917d127ecbe/6ce82e34-28df-4900-88ef-c932a446c6b0/1", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test=123&data=456"));
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16511#p40732 describes the process I recommend for posting data

Comment: the above example helped to get the data post successfully but, strangely, for the first time when the browser is loaded post request doesn't land on the URL but for every subsequent request, data is posted to the URL correctly. I am using the browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged event with if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized) check. On first time load, though the flag returns true, data don't land on the URL.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.Address = "https://webhook.site";
browser.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
browser.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
browser.RequestHandler = this;
browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
 if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
 {
  browser.LoadUrlWithPostData("https://webhook.site/#/cba9d04b-01ff-40ef-b223-0917d127ecbe/6ce82e34-28df-4900-88ef-c932a446c6b0/1", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test=123&data=456"));
 }
};

Comment: Update your question with your code and make sure you format it. That's unreadable.

Comment: Its updated now.

Comment: Did you try initially loading a data uri as suggested?

Comment: For the WPF version only you'll have to wait for the initial load to complete, I forgot we had a timing issue that was worked around by calling Load after the browser had been created. The other versions pass in an address to the CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser method.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/71/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L1749

Comment: Alternatively you can modify the request in http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnBeforeResourceLoad.htm change it to a post and append the data, you would no longer need to call LoadUrlWithPostData

Comment: can you give a code sample to modify the request using OnBeforeResourceLoad